# Gtk volume control bar

Tags: gtk

I want this kind of volume control bar shown in image.
Is there any GtkWidget?

[image]
Thanks,
KBalar

Answer (score 2):

You want an HScale.

You'll need to provide the volume images, of course, but the slider is an HScale.

Comment: In GtkVolumeButton if you click a button then volume scale bar pop-ups. I do not need this button. I need to have volume scale bar directly to be appear, not after button click.